# Text in the TextBlock is not trimmed properly inside the ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollviewer, textblock, texttrimming

As you can see [from stackoverflow post](http://ss.ss), this code doesn't trim the text of the **TextBlock**'s when the size of the **ListBox** becames small.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The **ListBox** shows the `HorizontalScrollBar` - in other words the room for **TextBlock** is large enough and there is no need in text trimming. This can be solved using the next line of code:

```
<ListBox ...
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ... />
```

So now the text will be trimmed. But if I wouldn't want to trim the whole text till the only **...** would stay? Let say, I have set the `MinWidth` of the **TextBlock** property, and when the width of the **ListBox** becames less than that `MinWidth`, I want `HorizontalScrollBar` becames visible.

I have tried to handle `SizeChanged` event, and according the condition, set the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` attached property. But the text becames not trimmed just when I change the latter from `Disabled` to `Visible` - so it jumps somehow - from trimmed to the full, which is not the best UI practice.

**Q**: So, how to achive the behavior mentioned above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TextBlock` in WPF really doesn't *want* to trim its text. It will do so when there isn't enough space, but as soon as the `ScrollViewer` can scroll, the `TextBlock` thinks it has infinite space available, so it won't trim.

I think the easiest way to do this is to set the `MaxWidth` on the `TextBlock` to the `ActualWidth` of the `ListBox`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is going to be ever slightly too big with the default WPF `ListBox` `Style` (which causes the scrollbar to still appear). I would write a custom converter to subtract about 8 from this value:

```
public FudgeFactorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return Binding.DoNothing;

        return (double)value - 8;  // you will probably need to tweak this
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

And then use it to convert the `MaxWidth`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <my:FudgeFactorConverter x:Key="fudgeFactorConverter" />
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Converter={StaticResource fudgeFactorConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

As a bonus, if you set `ListBox.MinWidth`, you won't have to enable/disable the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: This is really did what I want! But I can't figure out what is the **8** is resposible for? Is it the sum of margins, borderthicknes, or whatever else? I think that the key to the right solution is to compute fudge term correctly.

Comment: Yeah, it is the combination of the `ListBox`'s `BorderThickness`, and the `Padding` on the `ListBoxItem`. You could probably improve it to bind to the `ScrollContentPresenter` which will get rid of the need to account for the `BorderThickness`.

Comment: It work only when the Window is not resized. Otherwise it grows only and does not shrink.